# Accessing the same variable from multiple tasks

Tags: thread-safety, julia

Is it required to use locks (or mutex) to access the same (global) variables from different tasks (coroutines) in julia?

The julia document clearly specifies that the corutines use the same thread:

> produce() and consume() do not launch threads that can run on separate CPUs. True kernel threads are discussed under the topic of Parallel Computing.

In this case, do I need to consider any race condition between different coroutines while accessing the value of some global variables in different async tasks? Does the julia scheduler have any atomic operation characteristics on single assignment/access operations?

Comment: Julia 0.3 doesn't even have locks.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> Parallel programming in Julia is built on two primitives: *remote references* and *remote calls*

In other words, it's not *julistic* to program using locks, but by fetching values and remote calling.

See the `fetch()` and `@spawnat` example provided in the docs ([link](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/manual/parallel-computing)). You can also look up parallel examples in online repositories (such as [this](https://github.com/ajdecon/julia-wordcount/blob/master/wordcount.jl/#man-parallel-computing)).